# How to make a input fields border red if fields are empty and user is trying to submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to make a input fields border red when the fields are empty and user is trying to submit the form without entering the value. The fields border should become red while user is trying to submit the form without entering any value by using vue.js. Until form is filled the form should not submit.

**html**

```
<template>
    <div id="border_red">
        <input id="name" name="name"  v-model="name"/>
        <input id="name" name="name" v-model="age"/>
        <input id="name" name="name" v-model="phone"/>
        <input id="name" name="name" v-model="address"/>
        <button>submit</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            name:null,
            address:null,
            age:'',
            phone:'',
            
        };
    },
    methods: {
        
        }
    }
});
app.mount('#border_red');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to track the "submitting" state, and apply an `invalid` class for empty fields only when submitting, styling it with a red border:

1. Add a data property for `isSubmitting`.

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         isSubmitting: false
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. In the form's `submit` handler, set `isSubmitting` to true.

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       submit() {
         this.isSubmitting = true
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. For each input, add a class binding that sets the `invalid` class when `isSubmitting` and the field value is empty.

   ```html
   <input v-model="name" :class="{ invalid: isSubmitting && !name.trim() }">
   <input v-model="age" :class="{ invalid: isSubmitting && !age.trim() }">
   <input v-model="phone" :class="{ invalid: isSubmitting && !phone.trim() }">
   <input v-model="address" :class="{ invalid: isSubmitting && !address.trim() }">
   ```
4. Add a style for `.invalid`, setting `border-color` to red.

   ```html
   <style>
   .invalid {
     border-color: red;
   }
   </style>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-invalid-fields-upon-submitting-form-n3d47?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue)